# Saving image as eps

Tags: matlab, eps

I am trying to create a 2d histogram in MATLAB 2015a using hist3 using the simple following code:

```
figure
hist3([X,Y],[100 100]);
set(get(gca,'child'),'Facecolor','interp','CDataMode','auto');
colormap('jet')
set(gca,'TickLabelInterpreter','latex')
axis 'square'
xlabel('$x$','interpreter','latex','Fontsize',12)
ylabel('$y$','interpreter','latex','Fontsize',12)
view(-37,26)
```

where X,Y are two vectors with `length(X)=length(Y)=2026486`.
I tried saving the image in eps using

```
print('example','-depsc')
```

but the resulting image is pixel-based. I tried changing the renderer:

```
print('example','-depsc','-painters')
```

but MATLAB keep crashing while printing, so I have to restart the computer manually.
I tried also saving in pdf format but the quality doesn't change.
Is there a way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
fig_fname = 'example';
print(gcf,'-depsc2',[fig_fname '.eps']);
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply; I tried changing the code as you suggested, but i'm still getting a pixel-based image..

Comment: Try to root cause it: comment out view() and see what happens. And change hist3() to scatter3(1:10, 1:10, 1:10) and check.

Comment: Using scatter3 instead of hist3 (with and without view() ) I get vectorized image as I want; commenting out view() and using hist3 I obtain a pixel-based image..I also tried changing the length of the two vectors X,Y but the result is the same..
It seems that the problem lies in the use of the hist3 function..

Comment: I encountered the following tool. Check it out, it might solve your issue: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig